# Cuál es la correcta implementación de un PreparedStatement y ResulSet usando try-with-resources en Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy recibiendo muchos errores en Eclipse con el mal uso de la localización del `PreparedStatement` y `ResulSet`. Me he guiado de la documentación de Oracle pero, Eclipse me sigue marcando problemas.

Mi código:

```
public List<String> obtenerDato_UsuarioExistente(String id_usuario) {
        sSQL =  "SELECT FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario=?";

        List<String> dato_UsuarioExistente = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sSQL);
                ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery()) {

            pstm.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id_usuario));
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();
            rs.first();

            dato_UsuarioExistente.add(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(1)));  // id_usuario
            dato_UsuarioExistente.add(rs.getString(2));                 // nombre
            dato_UsuarioExistente.add(rs.getString(3));                 // apellido
            dato_UsuarioExistente.add(rs.getString(4));                 // usuario
            dato_UsuarioExistente.add(rs.getString(5));                 // contrasena
            dato_UsuarioExistente.add(rs.getString(6));                 // perfil

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        return dato_UsuarioExistente;
    }
```

Error que recibo en la línea `rs = pstm.executeQuery();`:

> The resource rs of a try-with-resources statement cannot be assigned

Según he visto, hay muchas formas de hacerlo, [en este sitio web](http://www.arquitecturajava.com/jdbc-java-try-with-resources/) indican lo siguiente:

```
try (Connection connection = getConnection();
Prepared pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet resultSet = pStatement.executeQuery()) {
while (resultSet.next()) {
// gestionar resultset
}
} catch (SQLException e) {
throw newException;
}
```

En la web de Oracle indican lo siguiente:

```
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

       // ........................
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    }
```

y muchos otros mas, enviando la sentencia SQL en lugares diferentes.

Estoy muy confundido, cualquier ayuda será bien recibida ya que estoy aprendiendo y no se realmente qué es lo correcto.

Comment: ups, mala mia, lo he quitado pero, el error sigue estando ahí. :( alguna idea?. @sstan

Comment: @sstan así es, indica el mismo error en la línea: rs = pstm.executeQuery();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay 2 problemitas con el código que tienes ahora:

1. Estás ejecutando `pstm.executeQuery()` 2 veces, y la segunda no es válida porque no puedes reasignarle a una variable (`rs`) que fue inicializada en el `try-with-resources` (eso es lo que el error te está diciendo).
2. En este caso, no puedes juntar la inicialización del `PreparedStatement` y el `ResultSet` dentro del mismo bloque `try`, porque necesitas asignar un parámetro al prepared statement antes de poder ejecutar la consulta.

Para remediar a esto, simplemente puedes dividirlo en 2 bloques:

```
try (PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sSQL)) {
    pstm.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id_usuario));

    try (ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery()) {
        // ... aquí usas el result set.
    }
}catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: vale, no sabía y tampoco me había dado cuenta. Permíteme hacerte una pregunta mas. Entonces la sentencia SQL nunca debe ir dentro del executeQuery(), en su lugar debe ir dentro de prepareStatement(SQL)?, es de esta manera siempre?.

Comment: Si usas un `PreparedStatement` (lo que es muy buena idea para poder usar parámetros) entonces sí. Solo usarías `executeQuery(SQL)` si estás usando un `Statement` mas bien que un `PreparedStatement`. Pero haces muy bien en favorecer el uso de un `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: otra cosa, he usado antes el ResultSet dentro del try junto con PreparedStatement y no me había dado problemas. Si tienes tiempo, mira este método que tengo con esto aplicado, para que me digas si es lo correcto, aunque no me esta dando error, si puedes y tienes tiempo. Screenshot: http://oi67.tinypic.com/vpz0pg.jpg

Comment: @RobertGomez eso debería ir en otra pregunta, puesto que básicamente es "¿qué diferencia hay entre `Statement` y `PreparedStatement`?" y ese tipo de cosas no deben contestarse en comentarios.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza cierto, vendría siendo otro tema, excúsame. Gracias sstan por ayudarme en eso, no sabía ese dato.

Comment: Asignar el `PreparedStatement` y el `ResultSet` dentro del mismo `try` es correcto siempre y cuando no necesitas ejecutar sentencias entre las 2 asignaciones. Por eso te funciona correctamente en tu otro ejemplo. Pero en este caso, necesitas ejecutar `pstm.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id_usuario))` entre las 2 asignaciones, por lo que debes separarlos en 2 bloques como te expuse en la respuesta.

Comment: @sstan entendido, todo claro. Muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda, se aprecia mucho.